# How to replace the content of the active text field with the current date?

Tags: javascript, date, replace

How do I replace the content of the **current** (i.e. **active**, with the cursor in it) text input field with the current date? or with any specified text?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you rephrase and elaborate on this? It's pretty convoluted right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.activeElement;//gets selected element
if(element.tagName === "INPUT"){
  element.value = new Date().toUTCString();//changes text in input element to today's date
}
```